# $B(x^{\lambda,\varepsilon};\varepsilon)\subset U\cap B(x^0;r)$ for what $\lambda$ and $\varepsilon$? (Evans proof)

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $U\subset\mathbb R^2$ be a bounded open set. Take $x^0\in \partial U$. Assume that there exist $r>0$ and $\gamma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ of class $C^1$ such that 
$$U\cap B(x^0;r)=\{(x_1,x_2)\in B(x^0;r)\mid x_2>\gamma (x_1)\}.$$

Define $V=U\cap B(x^0;r/2)$.

Given $\lambda,\varepsilon>0$ and $x\in V$, define $x^\varepsilon=x^{\lambda,\varepsilon}=x+\lambda\varepsilon e_2$.

[image]

Acording to [Evans book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=partial+differential+equations+evans&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizlqGj14nTAhWHHJAKHUV_AQgQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=partial%20differential%20equations%20evans&f=false):

> We can choose a sufficiently large number $\lambda>0$ such that $B(x^{\lambda,\varepsilon};\varepsilon)\subset U\cap B(x^0;r)$ for all $x\in V$ and all small $\varepsilon$.

I'm trying to get the bounds for $\varepsilon$ and $\lambda.$ According to [this notes](https://www.jku.at/analysis/content/e83492/e84520/e276762/sobolev_ger.pdf), the said inclusion holds for $\varepsilon <<1$ and $\lambda >>1$ but I can't see why.

**Attempt.** Let $x\in V$. Take $y\in B(x^{\lambda,\varepsilon};\varepsilon)$. Then $\|y-x^{\lambda,\varepsilon}\|<\varepsilon$ and thus
$$\|y-x^0\|\leq \|y-x^{\lambda,\varepsilon}\|+\|(x-x^0)+\lambda\varepsilon e_2\|<\varepsilon+\frac{r}{2}+\lambda\varepsilon.$$
Therefore $y\in B(x^0;r)$ provided that $\varepsilon+\frac{r}{2}+\lambda\varepsilon<r$. However, it seems that there is a problem here because this estimate gives a lower bound for $\lambda$ instead of a upper bound. Namely, it gives $\lambda <\frac{r}{2(\varepsilon+1)}$ which is not compatible with $\lambda >>1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small mistake in your computation. $\varepsilon+\frac{r}{2}+\lambda\varepsilon<r$ provided $\varepsilon(1+\lambda)<\frac{r}{2}$. So you first choose $\lambda>1$ and then you can take $ \varepsilon<\frac{r}{2(1+\lambda)}$.
To choose $\lambda$, take $y\in B(x^{\lambda,\varepsilon},\varepsilon)$. Then 
\begin{equation}y_2\ge x_2^\varepsilon-\varepsilon=x_2+\lambda\varepsilon-\varepsilon>\gamma(x_1)+\lambda\varepsilon-\varepsilon\ge \gamma(y_1)- \text{Lip}\gamma |x_1-y_1| +\lambda\varepsilon-\varepsilon
\\ \ge \gamma(y_1)- \text{Lip}\gamma \varepsilon +\lambda\varepsilon-\varepsilon
>\gamma(y_1)
\end{equation}
provided $\lambda>1+ \text{Lip}\gamma$.